# Get zoom level without getting recomposition for the whole GoogleMap

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-compose

I'm using Google Maps with Compose. I've got one problem to solve. I thought it will be quite easy to code but it looks like I'm missing something.

My Google Map in compose is quite common:

```
GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    properties = MapProperties(isMyLocationEnabled = true),
    uiSettings = MapUiSettings(
        myLocationButtonEnabled = false,
        zoomControlsEnabled = false,
        zoomGesturesEnabled = true,
        mapToolbarEnabled = true
    )
)
```

I want to skip recomposition when zoom level will reach let's say level 14. I want to change markers. I've got already markers. The whole list.

The problem is - every time I'm reading `cameraPositionState` value - the whole GoogleMap is getting recomposed (also markers).

I was able to limit number or recomposition by using this approach:

```
LaunchedEffect(localCameraPositionState.isMoving && cameraPositionState.cameraMoveStartedReason==CameraMoveStartedReason.GESTURE) {
...
}
```

But it's not the solution. The issue is - every time I'm trying to read `cameraPositionState.position.zoom` - it gets refreshed.

I want to push some event to markers when the zoom will reach 14 level.

What's the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna change your view on some state change, you can use [derivedStateOf](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#derivedstateof):

```
val isMoving by remember { derivedStateOf { cameraPositionState.isMoving } }
```

Now if you need `isMoving` in your view tree, recomposition will only happen when `cameraPositionState.isMoving` is changed, not when any of `cameraPositionState` variables changes - as long as you don't use `cameraPositionState` in other places.

---

In case you need to trigger some action, and don't need to recompose at all, you can use [`snapshotFlow`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#snapshotFlow):

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    snapshotFlow { cameraPositionState.isMoving }
        .collect { isMoving ->
            someAction(isMoving)
        }
}
```

Basically both `derivedStateOf` and `snapshotFlow` works the same: you can calculate result value depending on any number of states, and only if result calculation is different since the last calculation, state is gonna be updated or flow value is gonna be emitted.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue. I only wanted to recompose at a certain zoom for my markers. So I did something like this:

```
    val zoomLevel = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        snapshotFlow { cameraPositionState.position.zoom }
            .collect { zoom ->
                if (zoom > 12.715378f) {
                    zoomLevel.value = zoom
                }
            }
    }
```